# Java Click right

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener

I am looking for a keyboard listener, specifically for <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and the <kbd>click</kbd> , but it seems my code isn't correct.

mm is the mouse event

```
  else if (buton==MouseEvent) {

                System.out.println("Clic right");
```

So the first line is ok , because it prints "clic right" , but the ctrl doesn't work.

Someone know why?

Thanks

Edit : Resolved : event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 for the left click , BUTTON2 for the middle click and BUTTON3 for the right click ( uppercase ) and the method isControlDown for ctrl

Comment: Can you show some more code? What is mm?

Comment: Should work if you're using the right `MouseEvent` object (the same one you got `buton` from, right?).

Comment: Oh my god , trutheality , i considered the buton3 like the left button.
Thanks you for using the word " right " =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if( e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON_3 && e.isControlDown() )
            System.out.println( "ctrl + right click" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (button == KeyEvent.V_CTRL && mouse == MouseEvent.LEFT_CLICK)
         System.out.println("Clic right");
```

try something like that. i don't have eclipse open right now so i dont know if it works.